# Discord bot which deletes all messages from user

Tags: python, discord

I would like to write a code for a bot which will delete all messages from a person who leaves the server. Bot will ban him and delete messages. Do you have any suggestions what's wrong?:)

This is the code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member: discord.Member):
  await member.ban()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    async def on_member_remove(member: discord.Member):
TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'
```

EDIT:

I have fixed it and now code is like:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member: discord.Member):
  await member.ban()

client.run(os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN'))
```

I use replit to make my code. Bot works it is online but it doesn't ban or do anything with the user.
Have you got idea why?

I have also file ".virtualenv" and as well main.py

Answer (score 0):

Found [this issue](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1371#issuecomment-399718016) on GitHub, it seems to be the same error the you're having.

The issue is that you're not initializing the client variable as an instance of the `discord.Client` class but rather assigning the class to the client variable.